# Sharing information in application

Tags: ios

I am currently working on a new app, and I'm trying to figure out how I can implement the next thing on iPhone programming.

IPhone A writes a list of names in the application
IPhone B is notified and came to the application and see the list of names

My question is: how I share things between iPhones. A server that connects with the iPhone or what? And how it need to work.

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? you want something like PUSH NOTIFICATIONS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send data from IPhone A to server, then server send push notification to iPhone B, user start app on iphone B and download new data. If app running on iPhone B you should observer push notificating and don't forget to download new data...

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, that what I thought